# Returning the full path to an element?

Tags: jquery, html

I am looking for a way to find the full path to an element on click.

For example, lets say I have this HTML code:

```
<div> <ul> <li>item 1</li> <li>item 2</li> </ul> </div>
<div> <ul> <li>item 1</li> <li>item 2</li> </ul> </div>
```

I want to be able return the path (don't know what else to call it) to the clicked
element. alert() will do for now.

Lets say I clicked on the second li element in the second div. I would like a call 
back of:

```
div:eq(1) li:eq(1)
```

If I clicked on the first li element of the first div, it would be:

```
div:eq(0) li:eq(0)
```

How would I do this?

Is there a plugin out that can do this, or would I need to make it from scratch to get the index of element in the path?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you need this for? Also take a look at http://www.selectorgadget.com/.

Answer (score 6):

If you want the plugin approach:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        getFullPath: function(stopAtBody){
            stopAtBody = stopAtBody || false;
            function traverseUp(el){
                var result = el.tagName + ':eq(' + $(el).index() + ')',
                    pare = $(el).parent()[0];
                if (pare.tagName !== undefined && (!stopAtBody || pare.tagName !== 'BODY')){
                    result = [traverseUp(pare), result].join(' ');
                }                
                return result;
            };
            return this.length > 0 ? traverseUp(this[0]) : '';
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Specify a selector or object to jQuery and it will get the full path of it. `stopAtBody` is optional, but if supplied as true it will only traverse up to the `<BODY>` tag (making it a valid jQuery selector).

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pyF5S/)** (Click the LI to see their path revealed)

Comment: Wow! You rock Brad! Thank you.

I will look into it the code when I get time, but this looks exactly what I need. Would you like some compensation for such an amazing answer? :)

Comment: @user: Checks payable to Brad Christie, c/o Brad Christie Inc. --- Just kidding. I'm here to help others, not be compensated, though I do appreciate the offer. Glad to hear it's what you were looking for. ;-)

Comment: Hey Brad, is there a way to message you privately? I got a few questions about this and a way I am using it. I could pay for your time. :)

Comment: This doesn't actually work on [more complex DOM](http://jsfiddle.net/x1h7uepz/). `index()` returns the child order regardless of `tagName` and `:eq` counts same tags.

Answer (score 6):

This is how you can reconstruct the full path:

```
var q = $(this)
  .parentsUntil('body')
  .andSelf()
  .map(function() {
    return this.nodeName + ':eq(' + $(this).index() + ')';
  }).get().join('>');
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15051433/1338292).

Answer (score 2):

[.parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

would that do it?

Comment: I guess from what Danip said, I dont think it will give me the eq() of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read about the parents() function ?
http://api.jquery.com/parents/

You can get something like this

My parents are: SPAN, P, DIV, BODY, HTML

Comment: Doesn't provide the "eq(n)" qualifiers that the OP wants.

Comment: I can look into it. Is there a way to return the eq()? Index does that?