# Get all elements like myself in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Lets say I have this structure ( no classes , no Id's):  - it's a location finding question

*The d[0,1,2] are pure `divs` . no class no id.*

div (`d0`) wrapps a repeating structure like :

[image]

And let's say I have `$(this)` as the **first** `d1`

Is there any traverse function , method , solution for getting the other 2 `d1` ? ( or all `d1's`.it doesn't matter..)

I'll prase it with words :

> I'm `$(this)=d1`. I have a parent ( which is `d2` , can be more ....this is just for my  sample) which has a parent
>   (`d3` ) and  hence, I have 2 more exact elements like me.

how can I get them ? [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com/egewok/1/edit)

## edit

Maybe I wasn't clear but I don't have to know the structure. I just have `$(this)` and it should find by itself other twins relative to `d0` ( as same as its position)

so it should be something like :

```
function getLikeMyself(objWhichIsThis , contextDivElement)
{
}

execute : getLikeMyself(theDivWhishIsThis, divElemtnWhichIs_d0)
```

Comment: You should say: I may have X number of parents.

Comment: @Jack it doesnt matter cause I'm supplying the context div which is `contextDivElement` so me, as a child of child of... should seek my position according to this `contextDivElement`. ( and ofcourse find twins like me)

Comment: No, first you say "I have parent d2 and d3" and later you say you don't have to know the structure, i.e. there may be more parents (or less).

Comment: @Jack you are right. I'll enhance it.(edit : added it in the quote).

Comment: How do you determine the starting `$(this)` object? Or should all elements try and find all other elements that are like themselves?

Comment: @DavidThomas it is given. you have it.(the question also says so)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my new try, a `.me()` method that will return you the selector of the current element built up until the `body`.

```
$.fn.me = function(){
  return this.first().parentsUntil("body").andSelf().map(function(){
    return this.tagName;
  }).get().join(">");
};
```

Usage:

```
var selector = $(this).me();
var $twins = $(selector);
```

[See it here.](http://jsbin.com/egewok/19/edit)

---

An alternative version that accepts a root element as an argument:

```
$.fn.me = function(root){
  return this.first().parentsUntil(root).andSelf().map(function(){
    return this.tagName;
  }).get().join(">");
};
```

Usage:

```
var selector = $(this).me("#root");
var $twins = $(selector, "#root");
```

[See it here.](http://jsbin.com/egewok/25/edit)

---

A third version that keeps the relative position of the descendants of the topmost element under the root element. For example, it will return `DIV>DIV:nth-child(1)>SPAN:nth-child(2)` instead of a generic `DIV>DIV>SPAN` selector.

```
$.fn.me = function(root){
  return this.first().parentsUntil(root).andSelf().map(function(){
    var eq = i ? ":nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")" : "";
    return this.tagName + eq;
  }).get().join(">");
};
```

Usage:

```
var selector = $(this).me("#root");
var $twins = $(selector, "#root");
```

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear but I dont have to know the structure(otherwise it would be pretty easy). I just have $(this) and it should find by itself other twins relative to `d0`

Comment: @RoyiNamir, you put it well, you need to do it *by yourself*

Comment: That's quite a nice plugin. +1

Comment: There was a missing level. Updated.

Comment: can you please see what is wrong with my edit version ? http://jsbin.com/egewok/20/edit  (it bubbles till the html....although I told it to stop at the `contextDivElement`

Comment: @RoyiNamir, actually, you aren't passing the argument. [There you go](http://jsbin.com/egewok/21/edit)

Comment: M A G N I F I C O. ( just enhance your answer like my solution so people will be able to provide : `$(this)` and `contextDiv` )

Comment: @Jack, Nice, I think it is the first time I see you upvoting :O

Comment: @Alexander I have high standards =p

Comment: @Alexander  sorry. forgive me. my mistake. Im deleting not to confuse others. you were right.

Comment: @Alexander Is there any way we can make the last 2 lines into one ? (elegant way) http://jsbin.com/egewok/45/edit  something like `$(".d").likeMeUnder("#root").css("border-color", "blue");`

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yeah, it's fine. But, I prefer leaving the answer generic :)

Comment: FYI , if the div has sibling , it is not working as it should ( but i didnt mentioned it in my question which talks only about parents.) - but nevermind.... :-)  http://jsbin.com/egewok/53/edit

Comment: @RoyiNamir, [you can try something along these lines](http://jsbin.com/egewok/55/edit). This is only possible by defining a root element, even though there may be corner cases

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over each parent node and descend into their corresponding siblings, using the path that was built up on the way down:

```
var chain = [$('#imthis').prop('nodeName')];

$('#imthis')
  .parentsUntil('body')
  .each(function() {
    // i'm a parent
    $(this).siblings()
      .find(chain.join('>'))
    .each(function() {
      alert(this.textContent);
    });
    chain.unshift(this.nodeName);
  });
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/egewok/34/)

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear but I dont have to know the structure(otherwise it would be pretty easy). I just have $(this) and it should find by itself other twins relative to `d0`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function to "bubble up" the DOM until you reach the body element, then reverse this tree and use it as a selector. A little like:

```
function getChain(el){

    var parents = arguments[1] || [el.nodeName.toLowerCase()];

    if (el.parentNode.nodeName != 'BODY'){

        parents.push(el.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase());
        el = el.parentNode;

        return getChain(el, parents);

    } else {

        return parents.reverse().join('>');

    }

}
```

See **[a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpSRp/2/)**

Comment: I see you dont like jsbin that much...:-)