# JavaScript element identification and retrieval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the script found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360991/get-unique-selector-jquery) to get some text that defines the path to an HTML element. The results look something like this:

```
html>body>section:eq(3)>ul>li:eq(1)>div
```

How do I go about using either JavaScript or jQuery to select the element using these results?

Comment: `document.querySelector("html>body>section:eq(3)>ul>li:eq(1)>div")` or `$("html>body>section:eq(3)>ul>li:eq(1)>div")`?

Comment: That returns DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'html>body>section:eq(3)>ul>li:eq(1)>div' is not a valid selector.

Comment: did you try using $(...)?

Comment: Yep. Nothing givin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you save that string is stored in the variable "path", with jQuery you can do

```
var node = $(path);
```

and retrieve the exact element(s). The last "div" may have siblings of the same tag type and can retrieve an array instead of an element.

As for a JS implementation, it's a little bit hard. You'd have to reimplement [sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) or you can include it in your project and call:

```
var node = Sizzle(path);
```

jQuery node selection is based on it (when using complex selectors. it's a little bit smart and uses pure JS when detects ids, classes or plain tags).