# How to get css selector for an element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any jQuery plugin or javascript code that returns a CSS-selector that uniquely selects a particular element?

I'm looking for something with similar functionality as provided by the *Copy CSS Path* function in Chrome's developer tools, giving me a selector that looks something like this:

```
#question > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > div > h2
```

**Answers I tried**

[Get unique selector of element in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706837/get-unique-selector-of-element-in-jquery)

[Get unique selector jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360991/get-unique-selector-jquery)

Comment: What selector you want to get? Please try to provide more info.

Comment: _“to get the unique selector of an element”_ – there __is__ no such thing. Elements can be selected in a multitude of different ways.

Comment: Are you looking for a selector that *uniquely selects a particular element*, as opposed to a *unique selector for an element*?

Comment: @MårtenWikström Yes, like developer tools "Copy CSS Path".

Comment: @optimusprime: Then it's more clear what you're asking for. I've edited your question. Please provide links to the answers on StackOverflow that did not answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Just found this post, had a look at the only answer and got terrified by it's complexity and by bizarre denial from using jQuery functions. Sorry for criticism, but i really i got stunned by this callback system. Here, have it in easy to use form:

```
function getCSSPath(el) {
    let rendered_path_parts = [];

    $( el ).parents().addBack().each((i, el) => {
        const $el = $( el );
        let current_el_path = $el.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();

        if ($el.attr('id')) {
            current_el_path += '#' + $el.attr('id');
        }

        if ($el.attr('class')) {
            current_el_path += '.' + $el.attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
        }

        rendered_path_parts.push( current_el_path );
    })

    return rendered_path_parts.join(' ');
}

$.fn.extend({
    getPath: function() {
        return getCSSPath(this.length === 1 ? this : this.eq(0));
    }
});

getCSSPath(some_element);
some_jquery_element.getPath();
```

Note that rendered selector will not include element' index, so it is less descriptive than selector developer tools can make for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect, but written fast (for You) : )

http://jsfiddle.net/k1qs69fz/7/

**Code:**

```
function getCSSPath(el, callback){

    var fullPath = '';

    var cssPathFn = function (el, callback){

        var elPath = '';

        elPath = $(el).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();

        if(typeof $(el).attr('id') !== 'undefined'){

            elPath = elPath+'#'+$(el).attr('id');
        }

        if(typeof $(el).attr('class') !== 'undefined'){

            elPath = elPath+'.'+$(el).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
        }

        fullPath = elPath+' '+fullPath;

        if(typeof $(el).parent().prop('tagName') !== 'undefined'){

            cssPathFn($(el).parent(), callback);
        }
        else{

            callback(fullPath);
        }
    };

    cssPathFn(el, callback);
}
```

**Usage:**

```
getCSSPath($('selector'), callbackFunction);
```

Function is based on `tag` name, `id` and `class` names, `indexes` are not supported.

**Sample usage (for HTML code on JSFiddle):**

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    getCSSPath($('#lorem-ipsum'), function (path){

        console.log(path);
    });
});
```

**Sample Result:**

```
html body div#id1.c1.c2.c3 div#id2 div.c4.c5 span span.c6 ul li a span#lorem-ipsum
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure JavaScript implementation of what the others had using [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes#browser_compatibility) so it should work everywhere.

I made it a snippet so you can see that `document.querySelector` works with the selector found.

```js
function getCSSSelector(el){
    let selector = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
    const attrs = el.attributes
    for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
        let attr = attrs.item(i)
        if (attr.name === 'id') selector += `#${attr.value}`;
        if (attr.name === 'class') selector += attr.value.split(' ').map((c) => `.${c}`).join('');
        if (attr.name === 'name') selector += `[${attr.name}=${attr.value}]`;
    }
    return selector
}

let el = document.querySelector('input#id.abc');
let selector = getCSSSelector(el);
console.log(selector)
document.querySelector(selector).value = selector;
```

```html
<input id="id", class="abc def" name='name' style='width: 200px'>
```

Comment: I tried to use this function on kijiji.ca for removing an annoying element, the function should return "div.sc-58853b75-0.ofGHb" but instead it return this: "div.sc-58853b75-0.jOwRwk". That's weird because I can't even find the "jOwRwk" class anywhere in the source. Do you have any clue about what could be the problem here?

Comment: I used this function on other elements and it worked perfectly... I really don't know why it's doing this on this element specifically...